# Is there a way to get new Data on HTML without restarting the server?

Tags: html, node.js, express, raspberry-pi2

I have a problem with my node.js express Server. I got an audio file. Every 5 seconds my raspberry pi records another audio file with the same name. This audio file should run on my website. My website refreshes every 10sec, but the audio file which is played stays the same. How can I have the latest Audiofile played?

Here's my HTML:

```
e meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10"/> !-- Refreshes every 10 seconds -->
     /head>   body background="bg.png" >
         <audio autoplay><source src="Aufnahme.wav" type="audio/wav"/><a href="Aufnahme.wav"></a></audio>
</body>
</html>
```

(I know I don't have some "<" but it appears to not work here and I don't know the Escape signs)

And this is my Node.js Code, I'm also using express.

```
var res = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');

app.use(express.static('www'));

var server = app.listen(8000, function () {

var host = server.address().address;
var port = server.address().port;

console.log('Express app listening at http:\/\/%s:%s', host, port);

});
```

I think it is something about my Nodejs, can someone help me pls? Or didn't I grasp some concept of Server/Client? 
Sorry I'm new to this

Comment: It's quite possible, but there's quite a lot of ways to achieve this. You probably want to look at web sockets though, or maybe create an Express route and get your file from there by AJAX download instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your audio file is in browser cache...

So one idea is to simulate a versionning of your audio file...

For exemple in your code, genere a new Id call 'myNewId'.

In you html

```
<audio autoplay><source src="Aufnahme.wav?${YOU PUT YOU NEW ID HERE DEPENDING YOUR TEMPLATE ENGINE}" type="audio/wav"/><a href="Aufnahme.wav?${YOU PUT YOU NEW ID HERE DEPENDING YOUR TEMPLATE ENGINE}"></a></audio>
```